# No launcher in manifest?

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have 2 activity, I want to run one first. If I run this code, Console will write this: No Launcher activity found!, but i declared LAUNCHER in manifest?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.manif"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".splash"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.manif.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> //<--here is a problem, i think
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.manif.SECOND_CLASS" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to replace this

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.manif.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
 </intent-filter>
```

with this

```
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the action name to :

```
<intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use intent filter and other thing second time-

```
 <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

This code is enough for second activity.

Answer (score 0):

just remove tag:

```
<action android:name="com.example.manif.SECOND_CLASS" />
```